# XML elementTree cuts off text after a newline (\n) in python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm parsing a text and one of the children have text that is like the following:

"
Interdiffusion, which occurs in the presence of chemical potential gradient and results in net transport of mass, is an omnipresent but important phenomenon in a variety of materials processes, e.g., solidification, solid solution, aging, corrosion, mutual interaction between coatings and matrix, and so on [\n–\n]. Accurate interdiffusion coefficients (or interdiffusivities) are necessary for comprehensive understanding...
"

If this child's variable name is "body", I would extract it by using `body.text`. However, when I do, it cuts off everything after the new line and get something like the following.

"Interdiffusion, which occurs in the presence of chemical potential gradient and results in net transport of mass, is an omnipresent but important phenomenon in a variety of materials processes, e.g., solidification, solid solution, aging, corrosion, mutual interaction between coatings and matrix, and so on ["

This is my code:

```
file = "Articles Batch 1/Keep/s1.xml"
root = ET.parse(file).getroot()
records = root[4]
article = records[0]
body = article[1]
print(body[0][0].text)
```

How would I keep the whole thing?

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't very clear.  Please edit your question to include the code you are running and some sample XML data that causes the problem you are reporting.

Comment: I already included the relevant code and the relevant data...

Comment: Please also show us (a relevant sample of) the XML.We need a [mcve].